# Javascript Audio Player - Adding .ogg to .mp3 array

Tags: javascript, arrays, audio, html5-audio

I have my javascript audio player working with .mp3s, but I'm not sure how to add a second audio format (.ogg) so the files will also play in Firefox. Can anyone help with this. Here is the array code:

```
var urls = new Array();
    urls[0] = 'audio/song1.mp3';
    urls[1] = 'audio/song2.mp3';
    urls[2] = 'audio/song3.mp3';
    urls[3] = 'audio/song4.mp3';

var next = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to play sounds is with [SoundManager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) with uses Flash and HTML 5 when available.

Comment: I've tried to implement that (the 360 version), but I can never get it to work properly.